# Is it correct the use of "so" in this sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, so

I don't know if the use of so, it is possible here!

> *"we cant not protect our children from everything. **So** some plans won't make their way in their life."*

I found this on the Internet :

- In formal contexts we can use so instead of an adjective phrase after a verb:

The bus service was very unreliable when I was young and it remains so even today. (It remains very unreliable …)

- We use so as a subordinating conjunction to introduce clauses of result or decision:

I got here late. It was a long journey, so I’m really tired now.

[dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/speaking/so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences contain mistakes.

- "we cant not" is incorrect, it should be "can't" (or "cannot" and even less usual "can not")
- it would be more correct to use a comma instead of a full stop before "so" (although a full stop can be accepted in an informal context) - actually this may depend on the meaning of second sentence...
- "some plans won't make their way in their life": this part doesn't make sense to me. Did you want to say that some of the children will make their own way? Or that some plans won't suit the life of the children? Depending on the meaning of the end of your sentence, "so" may be used. However my feeling is it's not the conjunction/word you're looking for.

So here is what I recommend you.
- "We can't protect our children from everything, "
- "Some..." (please try to rephrase or explain this part as I didn't get it)
Analyse the type of connection there is between the two sentences. If the second one is a consequence of the first one, then you can use "so" between them. There are some other cases when you can use "so", as it's explained in the link you shared, but again we need to figure out the meaning of the second sentence first.

Comment: Generally, people use can't in speech and informal writing, and cannot or can not in formal writing or very formal speech.

Comment: that's what I mean "some plans won't suit the life of the children"